# Modulo Behavior C++

Tags: c++

I am working on following hackerrank problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

I am left-rotating the following vector (i.e. the values should shift leftwards `d` times):

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

where `d = 4`.

Here is my code for the rotation:

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> rotLeft(vector<int> a, int d) {
    vector<int> r(a.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){


        if(a[i] == 1) // debug output
            cout << (i-d) % r.size() << " ; " << (i-d) << " ; " << r.size() << " ; " << -4 % 5 << endl;

        // actual code
        r[((i-d) % r.size() + r.size()) % r.size()] = a[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

The code returns `5 0 1 2 3` instead of the expected `5 1 2 3 4`.

I have narrowed down my problem to `(i-d) % r.size()`. For some reason, `(i-d) % r.size()` is 2 instead of -4 (which is what I expected). The debug output is `2 ; -4 ; 5 ; -4`, which means `i-d` is -4, `r.size()` is 5 and `-4 % 5` should be -4. Why is this happening?

Comment: Pro tip: invert your worldview. Instead of figuring out where each cell is moved ***to***, figure out where the new vector value gets moved ***from***. The math is laughably simple: `r[i]=a[(i+d) % a.size()]`. That's it. End of story. This is too trivial to beg karma for it.

Comment: This might not be the answer you were hoping for but this question just shouts for [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: A signed number modulo an unsigned number will convert the signed number to unsigned before doing the divide.